# Populate variables according to column index and other values

Tags: r

I have a dataset containing observations of cases. In reality each case is observed at ten different time periods (P1 to P10) and can be in one of 5 states (1 to 5) at each period.

Each case is in state 1 at P1. A case can only progress from state 1 to 2 to 3 etc, and must pass from 1 to 2 before passing to 3 etc. A case does not necessarily change state during the observed period.

In my dataset I have the states of each case at P1 and P10 and also know in which period the case attained each state (S2 to S5 e.g. a value for S2 of 5 means the first observation of the case in state 2 was in P5).

My data is thus as follows:

```
# Create test dataset #

test <- as.data.frame(c(1:8))
names(test) <- "Obs"

test$P1 <- 1
for (i in 2:9){
  test[[paste("P",i,sep="")]] <- NA
}
test$P10 <- c(1,5,3,2,2,5,5,4)

test$S2 <- c(NA,2,4,9,7,3,3,2)
test$S3 <- c(NA,5,8,NA,NA,4,4,3)
test$S4 <- c(NA,7,NA,NA,NA,5,8,5)
test$S5 <- c(NA,9,NA,NA,NA,10,9,NA)
```

I would like to recreate the sequence of observations P2 to P9 for each case, fill in the blanks so to speak. I tried the following:

```
func <- function(base){
  for(i in 1:nrow(base)){
    if (is.na(base$S5[i])) {
      for (j in 2:9){
        base[[paste("P", j, sep="")]] <- NA
      }
    }
    else {
      for (j in 2:base$S5[i]){
        base[[paste("P", j, sep="")]] <- 5
      }
    }
  }
  base
}

test <- func(test)
```

I would like to populate all Pi columns where i <= the value of S5 with 5. Then do the same for S4, S3 and S2. The desired result being :

```
   Obs P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9 P10 S2 S3 S4 S5
1    1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1   1 NA NA NA NA
2    2  1  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  5   5  2  5  7  9
3    3  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  3   3  4  8 NA NA
4    4  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2   2  9 NA NA NA
5    5  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  2  2   2  7 NA NA NA
6    6  1  1  2  3  4  4  4  4  4   5  3  4  5 10
7    7  1  1  1  2  3  3  3  4  5   5  4  5  8  9
8    8  1  2  3  3  4  4  4  4  4   5  2  3  5 NA
```

As an addition, once the final transition has occurred for a case, I would like all following values to be the dummy value 9:

```
   Obs P1 P2 P3 P4 P5 P6 P7 P8 P9 P10 S2 S3 S4 S5
1    1  1  9  9  9  9  9  9  9  9   9 NA NA NA NA
2    2  1  2  2  2  3  3  4  4  5   9  2  5  7  9
3    3  1  1  1  2  2  2  2  3  9   9  4  8 NA NA
4    4  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  1  2   9  9 NA NA NA
5    5  1  1  1  1  1  1  2  9  9   9  7 NA NA NA
6    6  1  1  2  3  4  9  9  9  9   5  3  4  5 10
7    7  1  1  1  2  3  3  3  4  5   9  4  5  8  9
8    8  1  2  3  3  4  4  4  4  4   5  2  3  5 NA
```

For this last part I could use :

```
for(i in 1:nrow(test)){ 
  test$last_chg[i] <- ifelse(is.na(test$S2[i]),NA,max(test[i,c(12:15)], na.rm=T))
}
```

to obtain the column index of the last state change, but how would I populate all columns to the right of this with 9?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found an efficient solution :

```
# Create temporary variables #

test3$temp_P1 <- NA
test3$temp_P2 <- NA
test3$temp_P3 <- NA
test3$temp_P4 <- NA
test3$temp_P5 <- NA
test3$temp_P6 <- NA
test3$temp_P7 <- NA
test3$temp_P8 <- NA
test3$temp_P9 <- NA
test3$temp_P10 <- NA
test3$temp_P11 <- NA


# Function #

func5 <- function(base){
  for (k in 5:2){
    for (z in 2:10){ 
      for(i in 1:nrow(base)) {
        if (isTRUE(base[[paste("S",k,sep="")]][i]==z)) {
          for (j in match("temp_P2",names(base)):match(paste("temp_P",z,sep=""),names(base))){
            base[i,j-1] <- k-1
            base[i,j] <- k
          } 
        } else {
          for (j in match("temp_P2",names(base)):match("temp_P10",names(base))){
            base[i,j-1] <- base[i,j-1]
            base[i,j] <- base[i,j]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
  base
}
test3 <- func5(test3)

# Replace P2-P9 with correct values #

test3[is.na(test3)] <- -9

for (i in 2:9) {
  test3[[paste("P",i,sep="")]] <- test3[[paste("temp_P",i,sep="")]]
}

test3$P10 <- ifelse(test3$P9 == -9, -9, test3$P10)
test3$P10 <- ifelse(test3$P9 == test3$P10, -9, test3$P10)
```